# How to align columns in Golang logger?

Tags: go, logging

When configuring Golang logger to show the location in code (like the snippet in the [doc](https://pkg.go.dev/log#Logger)), the messages are not aligned.

For example:

```
$ go run .
main.go:11: From main
afilewithalongname.go:4: From function
```

**How to vertically align the messages "From main" and "From function"?**

Below, the MCVE.

File `main.go`:

```
package main

import(
        "log"
        "os"
)

var logger = log.New(os.Stderr, "", log.Lshortfile)

func main() {
        logger.Println("From main")
        SomeFunction()
}
```

File `afilewithalongname.go`:

```
package main

func SomeFunction() {
        logger.Println("From function")
}
```

File `go.mod`:

```
module testlog

go 1.17
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't have that much control over the standard log package. If you simply want to write to stdout you can use `fmt.Printf` which allows you to pad parts of your string. You can get the file name of the calling function with the `runtime.Caller` function. To get something like:

```golang
func log(msg string) {
    _, file, no, ok := runtime.Caller(1)
    if ok {
        fmt.Printf("%30s:%d: %s\n", file, no, msg)
    }
}
```

The `%30s` part means we will pad the string to 30 chars wide, this value will depend on your max file size.

I can also recommend a dedicated logging library like [logrus](https://github.com/sirupsen/logrus) which offers you more flexibility in the way our logs are formatted and where they are written to ect.

Comment: @ymudyruc, use [filepath.Base(file)](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Base).

Comment: @ymudyruc Ah, sorry. My mistake, will edit the answer

Comment: @caveman Mmmm... You were right! Sorry. When copied your code right at the line to be logged, it gave the location **one** frame above in the stack (that is the **1**). But after packaging the function like you, the **1** *is* necessary to obtain the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

While the `log` package in the standard library has [some flags](https://pkg.go.dev/log#pkg-constants) such as `Ldate` and `Lshortfile`, there is no option to affect the vertical alignment when printed to a console or file.

You would need to choose a logger from outside of the standard library. The default configuration of [logrus](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/sirupsen/logrus) will perform some vertical alignment when the output device is a TTY.